# How to overwrite or at least delete a remote file via cadaver with webdav server?

Tags: linux, webdav, cadaver

I'm sending backups offiste via webdav, they are on a monthly rotation so I just want my uploads to overwrite last months files on the webdav server:

```
cadaver https://files.server.com/webdav/ <<EOF
cd /backups/$APPNAME
delete $DBNAME$TODAYSDATE-db.aes
delete $APPNAME$LOGDATE-log.aes
put $BACKUPPATH/$DBNAME$TODAYSDATE-db.aes
put $BACKUPPATH/$APPNAME$LOGDATE-log.aes
quit
EOF
```

I get errors for the delete:

```
Deleting `repair21-log.aes': failed:
417 Expectation Failed
```

And for the put (it won't overwrite):

```
Progress: [=============================>] 100.0% of 232912208 bytes failed:
417 Expectation Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

FFS I had the user permissions set on the folder so that I couldn't overwrite or delete!

I gave full permissions to the user I'm logging in as on the folder, and now I can delete!